# Сортировка слиянием без использования дополнительного массива java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Нужно написать метод, который включает элементы одного отсортированного по возрастанию массива в другой отсортированный по возрастанию массив так чтоб в итоге получился отсортированный по возрастанию массив. Метод, который делает это с использованием дополнительного массива я написал, а без использования - не знаю как сделать. Заранее спасибо.

```
    public static int[] finalSortAuxiliary(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        int[] arr3 = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        while(i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length)
        {
            arr3[k++] = arr1[i] < arr2[j] ? arr1[i++] : arr2[j++];
        }
        if(i < arr1.length)
        {
            System.arraycopy(arr1, i, arr3, k, arr1.length - i);
        }
        else if(j< arr2.length)
        {
            System.arraycopy(arr2, j, arr3, k, arr2.length - j);
        }
        return arr3;
    }
```

Comment: Не уверен, что можно обойтись без третьего массива, если речь идёт действительно о Array, а не List. Насколько я помню, изменить размер существующего array нельзя, можно только создать новый array и перенести туда данные из исходного. А раз мы сливаем два массива в один, длина точно должна измениться.

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то, по-моему, можно так:

```
public static int[] finalSortAuxiliary(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        int[] arr3 = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];
        System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, arr3, 0, arr1.length);
        System.arraycopy(arr2, 0, arr3, arr1.length, arr2.length);
        Arrays.sort(arr3);
        return arr3;
}
```

Comment: "без использования дополнительного массива java"